# Matrix Addition in PHP

Tags: php, matrix, addition

I am trying to implement Matrix addition in PHP. I have looked at examples of similar implementations in C++ but haven't found a clear example in PHP. The error I am getting is that the resultant matrix displays '0' as it's cell values. Can someone guide me in the correct direction.

```
    $btn = $_POST['go'];
    $txt1 = $_POST['first'];
    $txt2 = $_POST['second'];


    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {
       for ($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++)
       {
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"first\" size=\"4\" />";
       }
       echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {
       for ($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++)
       {
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"second\" size=\"4\" />";
       }
       echo "<br>";
     }

    echo "<br><br>";

   $sum = 0;
   if(isset($btn))
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {
       for ($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++)
       {
         $sum = $txt1 + $txt2;
         echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"third\" value=$sum size=\"4\" />";
       }
       echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Try to debug yourself, add some `echo`s/`var_dump`s, verify if `$_POST` are empty.

Comment: @GabrielSantos I did. The post array is empty. It works when I do it with only 2 text boxes, but when I try to expand it into a matrix, I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If you can have two inputs with same name, add `[]` to then `name="second[]"`

Comment: When are you setting `$sum`, you're using `$txt1` and `$txt2` - they don't seem to be initialised anywhere

Comment: @andrewsi They are initialised from top `$txt1 = $_POST['first'];` and `$txt2 = $_POST['second'];`, when he send a form.

Comment: D'oh! I didn't scroll back up far enough!

Comment: @GabrielSantos I am not sure why the $_POST array is empty. When I add the values in the matrix, shouldn't that populate the $_POST array

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Matrix Operations](http://pastebin.com/RTdQSJzL). For examples, check out:

```
<?php 
include_once("Matrix.class.php"); 

// Data Array 
$ArrayDataMatriz1=array(4.021,3.831,4.021,2.560,2.716,2.612,2.638,3.869,2.664,3.945); 
$ArrayDataMatriz2=array(4.125,3.905,3.740,2.475,2.737,2.325,2.475,3.575,2.513,3.575); 
$ArrayData_MATRIZ_NxN=array(array(8,5,3,0), array(1,2,3,8),array(4,3,4,8),array(2,0,3,4)); 

$Matriz1 = new matrix($ArrayDataMatriz1); 
$Matriz2 = new matrix($ArrayDataMatriz2); 
$Matriz3_NxN= new matrix($ArrayData_MATRIZ_NxN); 

echo "<br>MATRIZ 1<br>"; 
print_r($Matriz1); 
echo "<br>"; 

echo "<br>MATRIZ 2<br>"; 
print_r($Matriz2); 
echo "<br>"; 

echo "<br>ARREGLO DE DATOS de NxN<br>"; 
print_r($ArrayData_MATRIZ_NxN); 
echo "<br>"; 


// sum of two matrices 
$suma= $Matriz1->SumaMatrices($ArrayDataMatriz1,$ArrayDataMatriz2); 
echo "<BR>SUMA DE MATRIZ<BR>"; 
print_r($suma); 
echo "<br>"; 


// sum of two matrices
$suma= $Matriz1->SumaMatrices($Matriz1->ArrayData,$Matriz2->ArrayData); 
echo "<BR>SUMA DE MATRIZ<BR>"; 
print_r($suma); 
echo "<br>"; 

//matriz de media 
$Matriz1->MediasMatriz(); 
echo "<BR>MATRIZ MEDIA<BR>"; 
print_r($Matriz1->ArrayMedia); 
echo "<br>"; 


//matriz de media 
$Matriz3_NxN->MediasMatriz(); 
echo "<BR>MATRIZ MEDIA<BR>"; 
print_r($Matriz3_NxN->ArrayMedia); 
echo "<br>"; 


//covarianza 
$cov = $Matriz1->CovarianzaMatriz($ArrayData_MATRIZ_NxN); 
echo "<BR>MATRIZ DE COVARIANZAS<BR>"; 
print_r($cov); 
echo "<br>"; 

?>
```

Comment: I think if you post the answer, he don't do the homework, and don't learn what he need to learn.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Ah! I didn't think in that sense. But, one thing is, the class that is used here is very advanced and I guess he can learn from this to create a basic way of how to make matrix operations. Obviously a newbie like him cannot submit something like this right?

Comment: He can learn with advanced librarys, but, this is a basic "question", so, it is important learn the basics first, and to go to advanced last.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Don't worry Gabriel I actually want to arrive to the solution by understanding. I can't say I understood what Praveen Kumar posted. I don't know if it's the correct answer but I don't know what is going on in that code. So you are right, explanation would have been better. Though I wouldn't mind a snippet of example, but obviously not the whole code....

Comment: @justbrianr When I say a library, it comes with two parts. One, the class part, which only the coder would have understood. The second is the activation part, or the examples on using it. Check them out. See how they work. Try to implement something similar. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks, I'll try to make sense of it. Would love to be at that level of understanding soon.

Comment: If you feel that learning PHP will be useful to your career, try considering Tizag.com and w3school's PHP tutorials. They cover from basic to advanced...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yea I know about that site. You are right, it is quite informative. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13330/discussion-between-justbrianr-and-praveen-kumar)